# Relationship between Fourier inversion theorem and convergence of "nested" Fourier series representations of $f(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

$\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}\DeclareMathOperator\sech{sech}\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}\DeclareMathOperator\sinc{sinc}$This is a cross-post of [a question I posted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840591) a couple of weeks ago which has not yet received any comments or answers.

---

In this question I use the term "nested" Fourier series representation to refer to an infinite series of one or more Fourier series versus a single Fourier series. Whereas a single Fourier series is periodic, a nested Fourier series representation is not necessarily periodic. When it is periodic it can be expressed as a single Fourier series, and therefore doesn't provide as much increased utility. The nested Fourier series representations for $f(x)$ defined in this question are of the non-periodic nature and even seem to converge globally for $x\in\mathbb{C}$ when $f(x)$ is a complex analytic function for which the Fourier inversion theorem holds.

---

A long time ago I noticed many series representations of functions derived from Mellin convolutions such as

$$f(s)=\left[\delta(x-1)\,*_\mathcal{M}\,f(x)\right](s)=\int_0^\infty\delta(x-1)\, f\left(\frac{s}{x}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\tag{1}\label{462653_1}$$

seem to converge for $\Re(s)>0$ (and in some cases for $\Re(s)\ge 0$) when formula \eqref{462653_1} above is evaluated term-wise using nested Fourier series representations such as

$$\delta(x-1)=\lim_{\substack{N, f\to\infty \\ M(N)=0}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(1+2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n} \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k x}{n}\right)\right)\right)\tag{2}\label{462653_2}$$

and

$$\delta(x-1)=\lim_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\right)\right)\tag{3}\label{462653_3}$$

where the evaluation frequency $f$ in the inner sum over $k$ in formulas \eqref{462653_2} and \eqref{462653_3} above is assumed to be a positive integer.

---

In Formula \eqref{462653_2} above, the upper evaluation limit $N$ in the outer sum over $n$ must be selected such that $M(N)=0$ where

$$M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)\tag{4}\label{462653_4}$$

is the Mertens function (which has an infinite number of zeros), whereas formula \eqref{462653_3} above eliminates this conditional convergence requirement.

---

Formulas \eqref{462653_2} and \eqref{462653_3} above actually converge (in a distributional sense) to $\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$, but the $\delta(x+1)$ term doesn't affect the Mellin convolution defined in formula \eqref{462653_1} above since the integral is over $0\le x\le\infty$.

---

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380164) to [one of my own questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980231/what-is-relationship-between-distributional-and-fourier-series-frameworks-for-pr) on MSE, I posted several examples of formulas derived from Mellin convolutions such as formula \eqref{462653_1} above using the analytic representation for $\delta(x-1)$ defined in formula \eqref{462653_2} above (see formulas (52) to (70) at my linked answer). As I mentioned above, many of these formulas converge for $\Re(s)>0$ which seems consistent with the fact that many Mellin transforms seem to converge for some subset of $s\in\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $\Re(s)>\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$).

---

More recently I noticed many times it seems the function $f(x)$ can be approximated by the nested Fourier series representation

$$f(x)\approx \lim_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1) }{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left(F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\right)\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \left(F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\right)\tag{5}\label{462653_5}$$

where

$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}\, dx\tag{6}\label{462653_6}$$

is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ and

$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[F(\omega)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega}\, d\omega\tag{7}\label{462653_7}$$

is the related inverse Fourier transform.

---

Formula \eqref{462653_5} above is based on the Fourier convolution

$$f(x)=[\delta(y)\,*\,f(y)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(y)\, f(y-x)\, dy\tag{8}\label{462653_8}$$

evaluated term-wise using the nested Fourier series representation

$$\delta(x)=\lim_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3}{8}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\\-\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 (2 n-1)}\right)\right)\right)\tag{9}\label{462653_9}$$

which is derived from formula \eqref{462653_3} above (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/418502) I posted to [one of my own questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361921/does-this-formula-correspond-to-a-series-representation-of-the-dirac-delta-funct) on MathOverflow).

---

I believe formula \eqref{462653_9} above evaluated at $N=\infty$ is equivalent to the limit representation

$$\delta(x)=\lim_{f\to\infty}\int\limits_{-f}^f e^{2 i \pi x t} \, dt=\lim_{f\to\infty}2 f\, \sinc(2 \pi f x).\tag{10}\label{462653_10}$$

---

Formula \eqref{462653_5} above is derived from formulas \eqref{462653_8} and \eqref{462653_9} above using the convolution theorem.

---

When $f(x)$ is an even function formula \eqref{462653_5} above simplifies to

$$f(x)\approx \lim_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\sum _{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\, F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\\-\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k x}{4 n-2}\right)\right)\right),\quad f(-x)=f(x)\tag{11}.\label{462653_11}$$

---

When $f(x)$ is an odd function formula \eqref{462653_5} above simplifies to

$$f(x)\approx \lim_{N, f\to\infty}\left(i \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \\\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\, F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right)\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\\-\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right)\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi k x}{4 n-2}\right)\right)\right),\quad f(-x)=-f(x).\tag{12}\label{462653_12}$$

---

**Question**: Can the Fourier inversion theorem be stated as follows? If the statement below is too broad, is there a way to qualify it with a set of conditions on $f(x)$ and/or $F(\omega)$ where it holds?

> A function $f(x)$ can be recovered from its Fourier transform $F(\omega)$ if-and-only-if the nested Fourier series representation of $f(x)$ converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

The statement above is not intended to preclude convergence over a wider range such as $\Im(x)<\alpha$ when $f(x)$ is a meromorphic function with poles at $x=\pm i \alpha$ for example, or even $x\in\mathbb{C}$ in the case of complex analytic functions. In general I believe when $f(x)$ is recoverable from $F(\omega)$, the nested Fourier series representation for $f(x)$ converges under the same conditions for which the inverse Fourier transform integral defined in formula \eqref{462653_7} above converges even though the Fourier transform $F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)$ and inverse Fourier transform $f(x)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[F(\omega)](x)$ are generally only considered to be valid for $\omega, x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

Table (1) below contains a list of example functions whose nested Fourier series representations seem to converge consistent with the conditions described in the previous paragraph. $F(x)$ in row 8 of Table (1) below is the Dawson function.

---

**Table (1)**: Examples of functions $f(x)$ recoverable from their Fourier transform

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \# & f(x) & F(\omega ) & \text{Convergence} & \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } | f(x)|  \, dx & \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } | F(\omega )|  \, d\omega  \\
 1 & e^{-x^2} & \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\pi ^2 \omega ^2} & x\in \mathbb{C} & \sqrt{\pi } & 1 \\
 2 & -2 x e^{-x^2} & 2 i \pi ^{3/2} e^{-\pi ^2 \omega ^2} \omega  & x\in \mathbb{C} & 2 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }} \\
 3 & e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(4 x^2-2\right) & 2 \sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-2 \pi ^2 \omega ^2} \left(1-8 \pi ^2 \omega ^2\right) & x\in \mathbb{C} & 2 \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{\pi } \left(1-2 \erf\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{4}{\sqrt[4]{e}}\right) & 2-4 \erf\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{8}{\sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi }} \\
 4 & \sech(x) & \pi  \sech\left(\pi ^2 \omega \right) & -\frac{\pi }{2}<\Im(x)<\frac{\pi }{2} & \pi  & 1 \\
 5 & \frac{1}{x^2+1} & \pi  e^{-2 \pi  | \omega | } & -1<\Im(x)<1 & \pi  & 1 \\
 6 & e^{-| x| } & \frac{2}{4 \pi ^2 \omega ^2+1} & x\in \mathbb{R} & 2 & 1 \\
 7 & 2 \sinc(2 \pi  x) & \frac{\sgn(1-\omega )+\sgn(\omega +1)}{2} & x\in \mathbb{C} & \infty  & 2 \\
 8 & F(x) & -\frac{1}{2} i \pi  e^{-\pi ^2 \omega ^2} \sgn(\omega ) & x\in \mathbb{C} & \infty  & \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \\
\end{array}$$

---

The remainder of this question illustrates some of the nested Fourier series representations of $f(x)$ for some of the example functions in Table (1) above.

---

Figures (1) to (3) below illustrate formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$ where $F(\omega)=\sqrt{\pi} e^{-\pi^2 \omega^2}$ and formula \eqref{462653_11} is evaluated at $f=4$ and $N=10$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (11) for f(x)=e^{-x^2}]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (11) for f(1+i t) where f(x)=e^{-x^2}]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of real part of formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(1+i t)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Re(f(1+i t))$ where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (11) for f(1+i t) where f(x)=e^{-x^2}]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(1+i t)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Im(f(1+i t))$ where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

---

Figure (4) below illustrates formula \eqref{462653_12} for $f(x)=-2 x e^{-x^2}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$ where $F(\omega)=2 i \pi^{3/2} \omega  e^{-\pi ^2 \omega ^2}$ and formula \eqref{462653_12} is evaluated at $f=4$ and $N=10$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (12) for f(x)=-2 x e^{-x^2}]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formula \eqref{462653_12} for $f(x)=-2 x e^{-x^2}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$

---

Figure (5) below illustrates formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$ where $F(\omega)=\frac{2}{4 \pi^2 \omega^2+1}$ and formula \eqref{462653_11} is evaluated at $f=4$ and $N=10$.

[image: Illustration of formula (11) for f(x)=e^{-|x|}]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of formula \eqref{462653_11} for $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)$

---

Comment: TeX notes: I think we've discussed before the unusual construction `\underset{\substack{N, f\to\infty \\ M(N)=0}}{\text{lim}}`.  I'm not sure why you'd want to use this when the presumably more natural construction `\lim_{\substack{N, f \to \infty \\ M(N) = 0}}` does the same thing.  Perhaps you are concerned that the limit might be off to the side?  As you know (because you did it with `\int`), you can insist that the limit appear below, even in text mode, using `\lim\limits`: $\lim\limits_{\substack{N, f \to \infty \\ M(N) = 0}}$. […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1205853)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1205852) Also, since you obviously want to make heavy use of numbered equations, you might as well get your money's, or at least time's, worth by accompanying your `\tag`s with `\label`s, which can then be `\eqref`d to get a clickable link, like \eqref{462653_1}.  Since these links are just to anchors, they even work across pages; for example, if you need to refer to \eqref{462653_1} in another question, you can link to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462653#mjx-eqn-462653_1.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Mathematica automatically generates the LaTeX you refer to as the "unusual construction" and I think its a waste of time to change it to what you refer to as a "more natural construction". I was aware of the capability you mentioned in the second comment, but I don't remember it off the top of my head as I've rarely used this capability, so thanks for updating my question to make the formulas linkable.