# Numerical estimation of partial derivatives of convolved functions when closed forms do not exist

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, jacobians

**Summary:** Some peak functions are convolutions which may not have a closed form solution. A classical example can that of a Voigt which is a convolution of a Lorentzian and a Gaussian, followed by further convolution with an exponential to impart asymmetry. Even if the derivative exists, it may be computationally difficult. In order to do curve fitting with optimization problems one requires gradients, in such cases, how do estimate the partials derivatively numerically to construct a Jacobian matrix?

**Details:** Many Peak shapes are asymmetric by nature such as those of molecular vibrations in solid carbon [here](https://bpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/blogs.gwu.edu/dist/a/1045/files/2018/02/RamanSpectrumLabeled-25hsdue.png). There are many commercial software like PeakLab (https://www.aistsw.net/Voigt.htm) that offer to curve "fit" these peaks with a Voigt function or better, a convolved Voigt to incorporate asymmetry. The Voigt is convolved with an exponential to impart asymmetry to these peaks. I am using Voigt as a general case, there are plenty of such peak functions that involve convolutions.

[image: Raman]

Consider the convolution of a Lorentzian function $f(x)$ with a unit Gaussian function $g(x)$, denoted by $h(x) = f(x) \ast g(x)$. Additionally, convolve the resulting function with an exponential function $i(x)$, yielding $j(x) = h(x) \ast i(x)$. The analytical solution or closed form expression for $j(x)$ may be challenging or nonexistent. How can one numerically estimate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial j}{\partial x}$ and higher order derivatives efficiently and accurately, particularly in scenarios where numerical methods are necessary due to the lack of simple analytical expressions?

To provide a specific example, let $f(x)$ be a Lorentzian function given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma}{(x-x_0)^2 + \Gamma^2}$$
where $x_0$ is the peak position and $\Gamma$ is the full width at half maximum (FWHM). Let $g(x)$ represent a unit Gaussian function defined as
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$
and $i(x)$ be an exponential function defined as
$$
i(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.
$$

We aim to compute the partial derivatives of $j(x) = h(x) \ast i(x)$ with respect to optimization parameters i.e., $\frac{\partial j}{\partial x_i}$, and potentially higher order derivatives.

I am trying to self-teach complex curve fitting problems using gradient based optimization approaches by least squares (say classical Levenberg-Marquardt method). For that we need a Jacobian. Given the convolution of functions with different functional forms and the complexity introduced by multiple convolutions, along with the absence of closed-form expressions for $j(x)$, what numerical or computational methods would be most suitable for estimating partial derivatives accurately and efficiently? Are there any specialized techniques or algorithms tailored for handling convolutions involving non-analytical functions, such as the specified example?

All I know that the particular PeakLab software author that it implements convolutions by FFT. How would we proceed with the calculation of numerical partial derivatives for the Jacobian in such cases (assuming closed form or analytical expressions are pretty difficult)? Would that also be done with the help of FFT or there might be an interesting convolution property that can help in those cases. Is there a good reference that covers numerical estimation of partial derivatives of convolved functions? Thanks.

Comment: The Fourier transform of the convolution of several functions is the product of their Fourier transforms. The Fourier transform of the partial derivative $D_k f(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ wrt $x_k$ is $cit_k F(t)$, where $c$ is a universal real constant, depending on how the Fourier transform is defined, and $F(t)$ is the  Fourier transform of $f(x)$. So, to get $D_k f(x)$, one can apply the inverse Fourier transform to  $cit_k F(t)$. Similarly, for the higher derivatives.

Comment: I think this is theoretically viable, but the procedure has numerical implementation issues (I recall a paper). I had also contacted the software author, he mentioned numerical differentiation, but I still do not understand the actual implementation for constructing Jacobian of convolved functions.

Comment: What "numerical implementation issues"?

Comment: This paper discusses them: Butola, Mansi, and Kedar Khare. "Calculating numerical derivatives using Fourier transform: some pitfalls and how to avoid them." European Journal of Physics 39, no. 6 (2018): 065806. DOI 10.1088/1361-6404/aadda6

Comment: From the definition of convolution, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f(x) * g(x)) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)) * g(x) = f(x) * (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x))$. Between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, pick the one whose derivative is easier to (pre)compute and use it in the convolution. For Lorentzian, Gaussian, exponential functions, the derivatives can be computed directly as formulas. Would that be good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine, This is a nice trick which may work for many cases, perhaps including the simple Voigt as well, because the other convolving functions may have easy to calculate derivative. After calculating the partial derivative one can do the convolution in the Fourier space. Would you mind writing an answer for a numerical implementation with an example for one element of a Jacobian? For optimization of the least squares residuals, it will be a multi-parameter function.

Comment: If you have regularly spaced samples there should be no problem computing accurate partial derivatives of the discrete convolution using any of the standard "tensor" libraries like TensorFlow, PyTorch and Jax. This kind of problem is what they're good at.

Comment: @DanPiponi, Yes, the samples are regularly spaced. I am not familiar with tensor libraries.

Comment: Is this toy example the kind of thing you're looking for https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gkkM_eUvmRdeANeVHR91sbUFzRoxDb-2?usp=sharing ?

Comment: Appreciate your time. I am not very familiar with Python as a chemist. I use MATLAB/Mathematica, but I can get the idea. Pardon, if I got it wrong. You are using an exact gradient with analytic convolution. What if we did not know the full analytical version of the convolution. A math colleague is saying, just do the convolution with FFT, and add the "step" do the convolution again and calculate the gradient by finite difference schemes.

Comment: Note it's not the analytic convolution - my code does a discrete convolution but computes the exact derivative of that. So in my toy example, f could be an array of measurements. It's also cheap to compute many partial derivatives simultaneously, not just one.

The numpy library in Python is a numerics library largely inspired by Matlab (but better principled) so you already have a basis for making the switch. :) Jax is a library that provides a subset of the functionality of numpy, but additionally can compute derivatives.

Comment: I think Matlab may have automatic differentiation support like Jax but for marketing reasons it's called 'machine learning'.

Comment: Thank you Dan for the input.

Comment: Numerical methods have their limitations. For example, can you evaluate the inverse Fourier transform integral $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)-\cos(k)\right)\, e^{-i x k}  \, dk$$ numerically?

Comment: Right for pure mathematical purposes, but for peak fitting applications numerical methods are necessary when the analytical derivative are near impossible to calculate, have look at these peak functions https://aistsw.com/docs/Generalized_HVL_Models.htm.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't address numerical methods of differentiation specifically, but illustrates that  even when its not possible to derive a closed form representation for the convolution $j(x)=[h(y) * i(y)](x)$, it may still be possible to evaluate $j(x)$ and the associated partial derivatives without resorting to numerical methods or alternatively only using  numerical methods of integration which seems consistent in spirit with the following excerpt from the question above

> Given the convolution of functions with different functional forms and the complexity introduced by multiple convolutions, along with the absence of closed-form expressions for j(x), what numerical or computational methods would be most suitable for estimating partial derivatives accurately and efficiently? Are there any specialized techniques or algorithms tailored for handling convolutions involving non-analytical functions, such as the specified example?

---

as I believe the approach outlined below falls under the categories of "computational methods" and "specialized techniques or algorithms". And even if one prefers to use numerical methods under such circumstances, the non-numerical approach outlined below could perhaps be useful as a double-check on the results obtained using numerical methods.

---

Consider the [Lorentzian function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html)

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\, \frac{\Gamma}{(x-x_0)^2+\Gamma^2}\tag{1}$$

with [Fourier transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformLorentzianFunction.html)

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}\, dx=e^{-2 \pi \Gamma |\omega|-2 i \pi x_0 \omega}\tag{2}$$

and [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\, e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\tag{3}$$

with Fourier transform

$$\hat{g}(\omega)=e^{-2 \pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{4}.$$

---

By the convolution theorem, the Fourier transform of the convolution

$$h(x)=[f(y) * g(y)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)\, g(x-y)\, dy\tag{5}$$

is

$$\hat{h}(\omega)=\hat{f}(\omega)\, \hat{g}(\omega)=e^{-2 \pi \Gamma |\omega|-2 \pi i x_0 \omega-2 \pi ^2 \omega^2}\tag{6}$$

and Mathematica gives the inverse Fourier transform

$$h(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{h}(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega}\, d\omega=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma+x-x_0)^2} \left(1+i \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma+x-x_0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma-x+x_0)^2} \left(1+i \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma-x+x_0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\tag{7}.$$

---

Now consider the function

$$i(x)=\lambda\, e^{-\lambda |x|}\tag{8}$$

with Fourier transform

$$\hat{i}(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty i(x)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}\, dx=\frac{2 \lambda^2}{\lambda^2+4 \pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{9}$$

and the convolution

$$j(x)=[h(y) * i(y)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y)\, i(x-y)\, dy\tag{10}.$$

---

I modified the definition of $i(x)$ in formula (8) above from the definition

$$i(x)=\lambda\, e^{-\lambda x}\tag{11}$$

specified in the question above because the Fourier transform and convolution integrals in formulas (9) and (10) above don't converge using the definition specified in the question.

---

By the convolution theorem the Fourier transform of $j(x)$ is

$$\hat{j}(\omega)=\hat{h}(\omega)\, \hat{i}(\omega)=\frac{2 \lambda^2}{\lambda^2+4 \pi^2 \omega^2}\, e^{-2 \pi \Gamma |\omega|-2 i \pi x_0 \omega-2 \pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{12}$$

Mathematica doesn't seem to capable of deriving the inverse Fourier transform

$$j(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{j}(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega}\, d\omega\tag{13}$$

but I believe the function $j(x)$ can be recovered from the "nested" exponential Fourier series representation

$$j(x)=\underset{N, f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1) }{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left(F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\right)\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \left(F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\right)\tag{14}$$

using $F(\omega)=\hat{j}(\omega)$ defined in formula (12) above where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and the evaluation frequency $f$ in the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

---

[My related MSO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462653) provides information on the derivation of formula (14) above (which corresponds to formula (5) in my related MSO question).

---

Now consider the partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial\, \Gamma^m}=\frac{\lambda^2 2^{m+1} (-\pi)^m |\omega|^m e^{-2 \pi (\Gamma |\omega|+\omega (\pi \omega+i x_0))}}{\lambda^2+4 \pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{15}$$

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial\, x_0^m}=\frac{\lambda^2 2^{m+1} \pi^m (-i \omega)^m e^{-2 \pi (\Gamma |\omega| +\omega (\pi \omega+i x_0))}}{\lambda^2+4 \pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{16}$$

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial\, \lambda^m}=2 e^{-2 \pi (\Gamma |\omega|+\omega (\pi \omega+i x_0))}\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\lambda ^2}{\lambda ^2+4 \pi ^2 \omega ^2} & m=0 \\
 \frac{m! \left(8 \pi^2 \lambda \omega^2\right)}{\left(\lambda^2+4 \pi^2 \omega^2\right)^2} & m=1 \\
 m! (\pi \omega) \left(\frac{(-\lambda-2 i \pi \omega)^{-m}}{i \lambda-2 \pi \omega}-\frac{(2 i \pi \omega-\lambda)^{-m}}{i \lambda+2 \pi \omega}\right) & m\geq 2 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)\tag{17}$$

---

Now for example, one can evaluate $\frac{\partial^m\, j(x)}{\partial\, \Gamma^m}$ using the nested Fourier series representation defined in formula (14) above where $F(\omega)$ is given by formula (15) above. I illustrated an example of this approach in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/464266) I posted to a related question.

---

I believe the $m^{th}$ order derivative of $j(x)$ with respect to $x$ can be recovered from the nested exponential Fourier series representation

$$\frac{\partial^m\, j(x)}{\partial\, x^m}=\frac{1}{2} \pi^m \underset{N, f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{(2 n-1)^{m+1}} \\\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k k^m \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left((-i)^m F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}+i^m F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\right)\\-\frac{1}{2^{m+2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k k^m \left((-i)^m F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}+i^m F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\right)\tag{18}$$

using $F(\omega)=\hat{j}(\omega)$ defined in formula (12) above.

---

The convolution integral for $j(x)$ defined in formula (10) above and the commutative property of convolution lead to the integral representation

$$j'(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} i(y) \frac{\partial\, h(x-y)}{\partial x} \, dy\tag{19}$$

of the first-order derivative of $j(x)$ where

$$\frac{\partial\, h(x-y)}{\partial x}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (-i \Gamma-x+x_0+y)^2} (-i \Gamma-x+x_0+y) \left(1+i\, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma+x-x_0-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma-x+x_0+y)^2} (i \Gamma-x+x_0+y) \left(1+i\, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma-x+x_0+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\tag{20}$$

and $i(x)$ is defined in formula (8) above.

---

Figures (1) and (2) below illustrate the functions $j(x)$ and $j'(x)$ recovered from the "nested" exponential Fourier series representations defined in formulas (14) and (18) above in orange overlaid on numerical evaluations of the convolution integrals defined in formulas (10) and (19) above in blue where all evaluations use the parameter assignments $\Gamma=2$, $x_0=1$, and $\lambda=3$ with respect to the underlying formulas (7), (8), (12), and (20) above. Formulas (14) and (18) above (illustrated in orange in Figures (1) and (2) below) are evaluated using the evaluation limits $f=4$ and $N=20$ using $F(\omega)=\hat{j}(\omega)$ defined in formula (12) above. The convolution integrals for $j(x)$ and $j'(x)$ defined in formulas (10) and (19) above (illustrated in blue in Figures (1) and (2) below) are evaluated via [numerical integration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumericalIntegration.html) using the [GaussKronrodRule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) method.

---

[image: Illustration of j(x) recovered from formulas (14) and (10)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $j(x)$ recovered from formulas (14) and (10) above in orange and blue respectively

---

[image: Illustration of j'(x) recovered from formulas (18) and (19) above]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of $j'(x)$ recovered from formulas (18) and (19) above in orange and blue respectively

---

Note in Figure (2) above, the evaluation of the formula (18) nested Fourier series representation for $j'(x)$ in orange essentially hides the underlying numeric evaluation of the formula (19) integral representation of $j'(x)$ in blue. In fact the absolute value of the difference between the two evaluations is less than $0.00015$ over the range of $-9\le x\le 11$ illustrated in Figure (2).

---

Note in Figure (1) above, there's a noticeable slight difference between the evaluation of the formula (14) nested Fourier series representation for $j(x)$ in orange and the numeric evaluation of the formula (10) integral representation of $j(x)$ in blue. I suspect formula (14) converges a bit slower, and this is related to the extra constant term $\frac{3 F(0)}{8}$ in formula (14) which can actually be emitted since

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda(1)}=0\tag{21}$$

where $\lambda(s)$ is the [Dirichlet lambda function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletLambdaFunction.html), but formula (14) converges better at modest evaluation limits with the constant term than without it which is why I included it.

---

I mentioned above partial derivatives of $j(x)$ with respect to $\Gamma$, $x_0$, and $\lambda$ can be recovered by evaluating formula (14) above using formulas (15), (16), and (17) above for $F(\omega)$.

---

The partial first-order derivatives of $j(x)$ with respect to $\Gamma$, $x_0$, and $\lambda$ can also be evaluated via numeric evaluation of the integrals

$$\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \Gamma}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial\, h(y)}{\partial \Gamma}\, i(x-y) \, dy\tag{22}$$

$$\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial x_0}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial\, h(y)}{\partial x_0}\, i(x-y) \, dy\tag{23}$$

$$\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \lambda}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y)\, \frac{\partial\, i(x-y)}{\partial \lambda} \, dy\tag{24}$$

where

$$\frac{\partial\, h(x)}{\partial \Gamma}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma +x-\text{x0})^2} (i \Gamma +x-\text{x0}) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma +x-\text{x0}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-i\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma -x+\text{x0})^2} (-i \Gamma +x-\text{x0}) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{-i \Gamma +x-\text{x0}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+i\right)-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}\tag{25}$$

$$\frac{\partial\, h(x)}{\partial x_0}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma+x-x_0)^2} (i \Gamma+x-x_0) \left(1+i \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma+x-x_0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i \Gamma-x+x_0)^2} (\Gamma+i (x-x_0)) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma-x+x_0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-i\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\tag{26}$$

$$\frac{\partial\, i(x)}{\partial \lambda}=(1-\lambda\, |x|)\, e^{-\lambda  |x|}\tag{27}$$

---

Figures (3), (4), and (5) below illustrate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \Gamma}$, $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial x_0}$, and $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \lambda}$ recovered from the "nested" exponential Fourier series representations defined in formulas (14) above in orange overlaid on numerical evaluations of the convolution integrals defined in formulas (22), (23), and (24) above in blue where all evaluations use the parameter assignments $x=0$, $\Gamma=2$, $x_0=1$, and $\lambda=3$ (except for the parameter associated with the partial derivative) with respect to the underlying formulas  (7), (8), (15) to (17), and (25) to (27) above. The convolution integrals for the partial derivatives defined in formulas (22), (23), and (24) above (illustrated in blue in Figures (3), (4), and (5) below) are evaluated via [numerical integration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumericalIntegration.html) using the [GaussKronrodRule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) method.

---

Figure (3) below illustrates $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \Gamma}$ recovered from formulas (14) and (22) above in orange and blue respectively where formula (14) is evaluated with $F(\omega)=\frac{\partial\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial \Gamma}$ defined in formula (15) above using the evaluation limits $f=4$ and $N=20$, and formula (22) above is evaluated via numerical integration where $\frac{\partial\, h(x)}{\partial \Gamma}$ is defined in formula (25) above.

---

[image: Illustration of partial derivative recovered from formulas (14) and (22)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \Gamma}$ recovered from formulas (14) and (22) in orange and blue respectively

---

Figure (4) below illustrates $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial x_0}$ recovered from formulas (14) and (23) above in orange and blue respectively where formula (14) is evaluated with $F(\omega)=\frac{\partial\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial x_0}$ defined in formula (16) above using the evaluation limits $f=4$ and $N=20$, and formula (23) above is evaluated via numerical integration where $\frac{\partial\, h(x)}{\partial x_0}$ is defined in formula (26) above.

---

[image: Illustration of partial derivative recovered from formulas (14) and (23)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial x_0}$ recovered from formulas (14) and (23) in orange and blue respectively

---

Figure (5) below illustrates $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \lambda}$ recovered from formulas (14) and (24) above where formula (14) is evaluated with $F(\omega)=\frac{\partial\, \hat{j}(\omega)}{\partial \lambda}$ defined in formula (17) above, and formula (24) above is evaluated via numerical integration where $\frac{\partial\, i(x)}{\partial \lambda}$ is defined in formula (27) above. The blue curve corresponds to the numerical evaluation of formula (24) above, and the orange and green curves correspond to the evaluation of formula (14) at the evaluation limits $N=10$ and $N=100$ respectively where both evaluations use the same evaluation limit $f=1$. These evaluation limits were chosen because in this case convergence of formula (14) seems much more sensitive to the evaluation limit $N$ than to the evaluation limit $f$. The evaluation in Figure (5) below is restricted to the right-half plane since the Fourier transform of $i(x)$ only converges for $\lambda>0$, and note that formula (14) is a bit slow to converge as $\lambda$ approaches zero, but the results illustrate increasing the evaluation limit $N$ improves convergence as $\lambda$ approaches zero.

---

[image: Illustration of partial derivative recovered from formulas (14) and (24)]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of $\frac{\partial\, j(x)}{\partial \lambda}$ recovered from formula (14) evaluated at $N=10$ (orange) and $N=100$ (green) and formula (24) (blue)