# Numerical partial differentiation of a convolution product with FFT

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, fourier-transform, jacobians, hessian

How can one numerically calculate the partial derivatives of a convolution function, particularly when the closed-form or analytical expressions of the derivatives are not readily available? I am dealing with the convolution of two functions, where at least one does not have an easily computable derivative in the convolution. I am considering a numerical approach involving Fourier transforms (FFT) to simplify the convolution operation, followed by a perturbation method for derivative estimation.

Specifically, let's denote the convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$ as $h = f * g$, where $f$ and $g$ depend on parameters $\mathbf{p} = [p_i, p_j, p_k, p_l]$. I am interested in computing the partial derivative of $h$ with respect to a specific parameter, say $p_i$, numerically.
Suppose we do the following:

1. Performing FFT on $f$ and $g$ to obtain $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{g}$, respectively.
2. Modifying the parameter $p_i$ by a small amount $h$ to get $p_i + h$ and then recalculating the FFT of the modified function.
3. Using the difference in *inverse* FFT results to numerically approximate the partial derivative with respect to $p_i$.

Example: For a Lorentzian function $L(x; p_i, p_j)$ and a Gaussian function $G(x; p_k, p_l)$, where $p_i, p_j, p_k, p_l$ are parameters of these functions, how can we accurately and efficiently compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}(L * G)$ using FFT and the described numerical method?

How would we go about calculating the Hessian elements numerically?

Is this approach viable for accurately calculating partial derivatives, especially for complex convolutions like that of a Lorentzian with a Gaussian, where analytical solutions are challenging? Are there any pitfalls or considerations to be aware of?

Comment: Can you give define the formula you derived for $h = f * g$?

Comment: For the continuous version: $(f * g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t - \tau) \, d\tau$, but since signals are discrete and sampled, we have to discretize time, and calculate f = zero centered gaussian at those times, similarly, one can use g as a Lorentzian at some location $x_0$, and calculate the Lorentzian function at those points. So basically, we will have a series of data points whose FFT can be multiplied to produce a convolution.

Comment: I understand the definition of convolution, but I was considering an alternative to your numerical approach. In your example, does $p_i$ correspond to $\Gamma$ or $x_0$ in the [Lorentzian](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html) $\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma}{(x-x_0)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2} \Gamma\right)^2}$?.

Comment: Steven, Right, $x_0$ would be one of the parameters, $\Gamma$, would be another one.  For the Gaussian, other parameter would be $\sigma$ and so on. Basically, the problem arises in curve fitting where you will need Jacobian.

Comment: isn't this the same question as your earlier https://mathoverflow.net/q/463917/11260 ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, Yes, this time I wanted to solely focus if FFT is a viable way. I am sure there must be a simple numerical way to calculate partials of convolution products.

Answer (score 0):

This "answer" doesn't address the question specifically, but outlines what might be a possible alternative to the numerical approach in the question.

---

Consider the [Lorentzian function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html)

$$L(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma}{(x-x_0)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2} \Gamma\right)^2}\tag{1}$$

with [Fourier transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformLorentzianFunction.html)

$$\hat{L}(\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty L(x)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}\, dx=e^{-2 \pi i x_0 \omega-\pi \Gamma |\omega|}\tag{2}$$

and [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)

$$G(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\tag{3}$$

with Fourier transform

$$\hat{G}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma^2}}\, \sigma\, e^{-2 \pi i \mu \omega-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 \omega^2}\tag{4}.$$

---

By the convolution theorem, the Fourier transform of the convolution

$$h(x)=[L(y) * G(y)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} L(y)\, G(x-y)\, dy\tag{5}$$

is

$$\hat{h}(\omega)=\hat{L}(\omega)\, \hat{G}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma^2}} \sigma \exp\left(-2 i \pi (\mu+x_0) \omega-2 \pi^2 \sigma^2 \omega^2-\pi \Gamma |\omega|\right)\tag{6}.$$

---

Mathematica gives the inverse Fourier transform

$$h(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{h}(\omega)\, e^{2 \pi i x \omega}\, d\omega=\frac{e^{-\frac{(i \Gamma-2 \mu+2 x-2 x_0)^2}{8 \sigma^2}} \left(1+i\, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{i \Gamma-2 \mu+2 x-2 x_0}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)\right)+e^{-\frac{(i \Gamma+2 \mu-2 x+2 x_0)^2}{8 \sigma^2}} \left(1-i\, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{-i \Gamma-2 \mu+2 x-2 x_0}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}\tag{7}$$

which I believe can be represented as the "nested" exponential Fourier series

$$h(x)=\underset{N, f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1) }{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left(F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\right)\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \left(F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\right)\tag{8}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), the evaluation frequency $f$ in the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer, and $F(\omega)=\hat{h}(\omega)$ defined in formula (6) above.

---

[My related MSO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462653) provides information on the derivation of formula (8) above (which corresponds to formula (5) in my related MSO question).

---

Now consider the derivatives

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)}{\partial\, \Gamma^m}=(-\pi\, |\omega|)^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)\tag{9}$$

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)}{\partial\, x_0^m}=(-2 \pi i \omega)^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)\tag{10}$$

$$\frac{\partial^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)}{\partial\, \mu^m}=(-2 \pi i \omega)^m\, \hat{h}(\omega)\tag{11}$$

and note that formulas (10) and (11) above give the same result.

---

The $m^{th}$ order derivative of $\hat{h}(\omega)$ with respect to $\sigma$ is a bit more complicated, but the first few are given in Table (1) below, and the general result can be defined recursively.

---

**Table (1)**: $m^{th}$ order derivatives of $\hat{h}(\omega)$ with respect to $\sigma$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 m & \frac{\partial^m\,\hat{h}(\omega)}{\partial\, \sigma^m} \\
 1 & -4 \pi^2 \sigma \omega^2\, \hat{h}(\omega) \\
 2 & 4 \pi^2 \omega^2 \left(4 \pi^2 \sigma^2 \omega^2-1\right) \hat{h}(\omega) \\
 3 & \left(48 \pi^4 \sigma \omega^4-64 \pi^6 \sigma^3 \omega^6\right) \hat{h}(\omega) \\
 4 & 16 \pi^4 \omega^4 \left(16 \pi^4 \sigma^4 \omega^4-24 \pi^2 \sigma^2 \omega^2+3\right) \hat{h}(\omega) \\
\end{array}$$

---

Now for example, this seems to suggest one can evaluate $\frac{\partial^m\, h(x)}{\partial\, \Gamma^m}$ using the nested Fourier series representation defined in formula (8) above where $F(\omega)$ is given by formula (9) above. For illustration purposes consider the specific case

$$f(\Gamma)=\frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial\, \Gamma}=\\\frac{i \left(-\sqrt{2 \pi} e^{\frac{1}{8} (\Gamma+i)^2} (\Gamma+i) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1-i \Gamma}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)+i\right)+\sqrt{2 \pi} e^{\frac{1}{8} (\Gamma-i)^2} (\Gamma-i) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1+i \Gamma}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)-i\right)+8 i\right)}{16 \pi},\quad x=0\land x_0=\frac{1}{2}\land\sigma=1\land\mu=-1\tag{12}.$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the nested exponential Fourier series representation defined in formula (8) above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(\Gamma)$ defined in formula (12) above where formula (8) above is evaluated using the evaluation limits $f=4$ and $N=20$ and $F(\omega)=\frac{\partial\, \hat{h}(\omega)}{\partial\, \Gamma}=-\pi |\omega|\, \hat{h}(\omega)$ (using the same parameter assignments specified at the end of formula (12) above).

---

[image: Illustration of representation of f(Gamma) derived from formula (8) above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function f(Gamma)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of representation of $f(\Gamma)$ derived from formula (8) above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(\Gamma)$ defined in formula (12) above.

Comment: Steven, Thanks for the input. The example of Lorentzian * Gaussian was generic one. The peak functions I am dealing with are worse than that. They have incomplete gamma functions and much more. There must be a simpler way of calculating the numerical partial derivatives, in a purely numeric manner.

Comment: @AChem Formulas (9) to (11) above and even the results in Table (1) above are not particularly complicated, and your question specifically asked about "complex convolutions like that of a Lorentzian with a Gaussian". If your real desire is to evaluate more complex convolutions than "that of a Lorentzian with a Gaussian", why did you use this as your example? I feel like your question is beginning to become a moving target.

Comment: Steven, Gaussian and Lorentzians are indeed one of them. But we can further convolve the Voigt with a half-Gaussian to make it asymmetric. In such cases closed form of f*g*k might be even more complex. I am sure there must be purely numeric way to calculate partials in such cases. One of the peak fitting software author told me that he uses FFT to perform convolutions. Since it is a peak fitting software, he must be estimating the Jacobians some way or the other-purely numerically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by half-Gaussian, but perhaps $i(x)=\lambda\, e^{-\lambda\, |x|}$ would be better than $i(x)=\lambda\, e^{-\lambda\, x}$ in your related question since with your definition the Fourier transform of $i(x)$ diverges and I suspect the convolution $j(x)=[h(y) \ast i(y)](x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty h(y)\, i(x-y)\, dy$ diverges as well. But I also don't know what you mean by asymmetric, so perhaps convolution with $i(x)=\lambda\, e^{-\lambda\, |x|}$ doesn't result in your definition of asymmetric.